# add check file existences function while search and copy file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have use sudo find all files which match the file type and copy it to a file directory then tee the report.
I would like to include function to check file existence so that file from different folder will not overwrite the wrong file.

Please suggest an idea to fix my function also. Thank you.

```
sudo find / -iname "*.@fileType" -cp -v {} $directory \; | tee report.txt

function checkFile(){
    if [ -f #filename];
    then
        # add number
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `-exec`  option of find:

```
find / -type f -iname "*.@filetype" -exec cp --backup=numbered {} $directory \; -exec echo {}  >> report.txt \;
```

With:

`-exec cp --backup=numbered` Will execute `cp` for each found file, with option `--backup=numbered`, which will prevent overwritting

`-exec {} >> report.txt` Which will add the copied file name to the report file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but in the backup folder still just save 1 of the file, other file with same name from different directory is not saved to backup folder.

Comment: @Tomeikun I'm not sure to understand what you want. If two different files have the same name, you want to save both or only first? Could you update you question to precise that point?